# Apply folding to block sequence of YAML in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, yaml, folding

I have some YAML files & I want Notepad++ to code fold a mapping (in YAML it is a block sequence). For instance in this example:

```
TerrainGeometryMap:
- - [G, W]
  - [G, G]
  - [G, G]
- - [G, G]
  - [G, G]
  - [G, G]
```

I want to fold the entire `TerrainGeometryMap` mapping. Notepad++ does what I want if the YAML mapping is formatted with an extra indent, i.e.

```
TerrainGeometryMap:
  - - [D, G]
    - [D, G]
    - [K]
  - - [D, G]
    - [D, G]
    - [D, G]
```

Is there a way to entirely fold the first map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You found a YAML lexer bug.

As discussed, I originally thought your first case should not lead to same folding as second one, but then I checked **Example 10.4** in [YAML 1.1 specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html#id931973) (implemented by SnakeYAML) and **Example 4.19** in [YAML 1.0 specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2564804) and found that your expectation on folding is valid.

**Scintilla editor (upon which Notepad++ is built) isn't folding YAML block sequences right**.

You can

- report the issue in [Notepad++ bugtracker](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) (I could not find it on the list there yet)

  - **maybe even better can be to report the issue in [Scintilla bugtracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/) because it is them who are actually maintaining lexers (not Notepad++).** Hopefully the fix will then get propagated into Notepad++ soon

> UPDATE: I registered the bug as [#1847](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/1847/). You can check there to see its status.

- fix the issue by yourself by editing method `FoldYAMLDoc()` in module `scintilla\lexers\LexYAML.cxx` which you can find in Notepad++ source archive file. If you can then rebuild your Notepad++ binaries, you should get it working
- find [some other editor with code folding support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Programming_features) which has YAML lexer

Comment: I think the problem was the example I gave above displays correctly in browser, but has extra whitespace when copy / pasted into Notepad++. I've added an example that looks wrong in a browser, but will copy / paste in a manner that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not asserting a problem with Notepad++ YAML lexer, rather, I'm wondering if it's possible to tweak it to display as desired. If not, I'll mark this as the answer. 
The YAML in question is from the SnakeYAML emitter, but as you suggest, it might be easier to solve the problem from that end.

Comment: Upon further research, I disagree with your assertion that all three elements are on the same level. According to the [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2799784) `Since people perceive the “-” indicator as indentation, nested block sequences may be indented by one less space to compensate`

Comment: @Pikalek – it seems we were doing the same research at the same time. :) See the updated answer. I also checked YAML 1.0 to learn whether this changed between 1.0 and 1.1 or not.  It did not.